# Issue with z-index positioning of elements in html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a jquery autocomplete function in this page:

[link](http://www.pikefin.com/phpdev/charts/allassets/linechart.php?a=660&title=All%20Assets%20Indivdual%20Line%20Charts)

If, for example, you type a 't' in the "Enter entity name" text field, a list of items is displayed. The problem is that the full list is obscured by the chart. How do I specify the z-index value for the dynamically displayed part of the auto complete element? I tried putting a z-index value in the div but that didn't work.

Comment: The chart doesn't seem to be loading, which makes your problem difficult to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the element has to be absolutely positioned for z-index to work

Comment: So absolute positioning is the only option?

Comment: According to http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_z-index.asp, "Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed)"